# Graphics.DrawImage shrinking image on display?

Tags: c#, drawimage, sizing

> edit: Thank you for all the responses, I just found that bmpSize fixed the size. I also added an array per Plutonix's suggestion. Thank you everyone!

Developing a game using Visual Studio, new to using C# for programming. I am generating a map from a text file using a switch statement and the Graphics.DrawImage method. The images are scaled at 24x24 pixels, and the canvas is 979x571. For some reason, my images are displaying very small. I've tried resizing using the Graphics.DrawImage method given, but it creates scaling on only a strip of the tiles. ((I can add the code I tried to implement this as well. Trying to keep this brief.))

I have a larger player object on the map for size reference, the map should be sized larger like the yellow player.

```
                case 'W':
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.wall, countCol, countRow);
                    countCol = countCol + 8;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.grass, countCol, countRow);
                    countCol = countCol + 8;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.player, countCol, countRow);
                    countCol = countCol + 8;
                    break;
```

[The map scaled much smaller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w8fX.jpg)

Comment: Load those resources into a collection or array.  As is, you are creating a new one each time and not disposing of them so your app is leaking

Comment: Look into the __dpi resolution__ values of the images. They __need__ to be the same as the screen (i.e. as e.Graphics.dpiXY) before you draw them (unless you use a DrawImage overload that sets the target rectangle)

Comment: Thank you for all the responses, I just found that bmpSize fixed the size. I also added an array per Plutonix's suggestion. Thank you everyone!